# Google sheet pivot table calculated field with if statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

I'd like some help regarding pivot tables calculated parameter in google sheet.
I have a pivot table where i count how many instances are listed in data table.

In my data table i have a column with date. I do not need that data in pivot table.

However, I'd like to count all values in data table that are older than 10 days and display those next to all values.

I have tried to use calculated parameter with this formula =IF((TODAY() - Created) > 10, 1, 0) expecting that pivot table would add 1 and display how many instances are older than 10 days. But it does not work.

What I did I added extra column in data table with this formula =IF((TODAY() - I2) > 10, 1, 0 ) and added the the values to pivot table. Everything works, but i need to update this column every time I add new values to tada table.

**Is there a way calculate older instances in one column using calculated field?
**
[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG2W2.png)

I have tried to use calculated parameter with this formula =IF((TODAY() - Created) > 10, 1, 0) expecting that pivot table would add 1 and display how many instances are older than 10 days. But it does not work.

I'd like to count all values in data table that are older than 10 days and display those next to all values. Red arrow shows total values, green arrow shows total values that are older than 10 days
[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgsvK.png)

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output.